# emacs python2.7

Tags: emacs, python

I would like to have emacs work as a python ide for me. I can't seem to find how to compile from within emacs. I'm using python2.7 but when I do M-x python-mode it seems to compile using python2.7. Is there some command which I could bind to some key so that I can quickly run my code and see the output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Short, unhelpful answer: press `C-c C-c`.**

You can get help on the current mode(s) in use by typing `C-h m` in Emacs. With a little bit of reading through the various commands supported and a couple of mouse clicks, I found this: in an Emacs buffer holding Python source, pressing `C-c C-c` (that's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>) sends the source to the Python interpreter.

The ‘inferior’ (nothing to do with quality) Python interpreter runs in a buffer named `*Python*`. You can press `C-x 2` to split the window, then `C-x o` (that's the letter oh) to move to the bottom window, then with `C-X b *Python*`<kbd>Enter</kbd>, select the `*Python*` buffer. After that, go back to the source window (`C-x o`) and use `C-c C-c` whenever you want to run your Python program. This is what it looks like:

[image]

You can obviously do all this with a mouse if you don't like keyboard commands. And if you go through the documentation for `python-mode`, you'll find Emacs commands to send individual functions, classes etc. to the interpreter. Try `M-x python-send`<kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> for a list.